# iOS - Swift - heightForRowAtIndexPath "rubber-banding" issues

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a UITableView with variable cell heights that are calculated based on the size of the text.

Within the heightForRowAtIndexPath function, if I return a simple number, such as 72.0, the table view looks and works fine, but obviously text becomes cut off.

If I have any sort of calculation, however, such as a simple one below, the rubber-banding effect you normally see when you scroll up or down too far completely disappears and the table view "snaps" to where it should end up.

```
return CGFloat(arc4random() % UInt32(100))
```

The code above is just used to show that any sort of simple calculation causes this error, but this is the actual code I'm trying:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    var article = articles.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NewsArticle

    var attributes: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: theme.newsHomeArticleTitleFont, NSFontAttributeName)
    var titleText = article.title as NSString
    var titleRect = titleText.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 64, 128), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)

    return titleRect.height + 52.0
}
```

I should also point out that the rubber-banding only disappears if one or more cells disappears from view while scrolling, as I believe it is only when a new cell needs to be drawn that this problem occurs.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: Strange new development, if I change the font size from 17 to 15, the rubber-banding works again, despite the fact that the reduction in font size doesn't change the number of lines or anything like that.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but the actual term concerning the "rubber-band effect" is called "bounce". Try running some searches with that term and hopefully you can run across a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like yours. I clicked on the tableview in the storyboard and then click the attribute inspector on the sidebar. Then I un-ticked the enable paging option.
I hope it can help!